# How to set priority to scheduled task?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I've got 3 tasks. 1st - adds new data. 2nd - backups. 3rd - deletes old data. They work every 10 minutes. How it should be:

```
1st task
2nd task
3rd task
```

What I've got:

```
2nd task
1st task
3rd task
```

How can I set priority to tasks?

Comment: If they have to happen in order why not just do them as one task?

Comment: You have set spring as tag. Is the use of spring a requirement?

Comment: Because one of the tasks may crash.

Comment: `@Scheduled` is Spring annotation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a java [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) you can provide your own task queue to be used internally by it, you should not interact with the queue directly.

You can use a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) constructed with a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that returns which task goes first.

You can combine @Scheduled annotation with a custom executor as explained [here in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html):

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableScheduling
 public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
     @Override
     public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
         taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
     }
     @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
     public Executor taskExecutor() {
         return new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 2, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20, new Comparator<Runnable2>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(Runnable2 o1, Runnable2 o2) {
                 return o1.getPriority().compareTo(o2.getPriority());
             }
         }));
     }
 }
```

Having a Runnable2 class that implements Runnable and has an assigned priority for example.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into converting these tasks to a [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) job. This would provide more powerful features such as transactions and better error handling.